# Why does my script continue to 'while' loop when if statement is true?

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype

At line 11, where the user chooses the cancel button on the `easyGui. enterbox`:

#### Code

```
from easygui import*

def  children_menu():
    title2 = "Children."
    children_menu = ["1: Register a child.", "2: List of registered children."]
    button = buttonbox("Choose an option", title2, choices=children_menu)

    if button == children_menu[0]:
        enter1 = enterbox(msg="Enter the child's first name.", title=' ', default='', strip=True, image=None, root=None)
        if enter1 is None:
            main()
            return
        else:
            while enter1 == "" or enter1.isalpha() == False:
                enter1 = enterbox(msg="Invalid entry. Please enter the child's first name using letters only.",title=' ', default='', strip=True, image=None, root=None)

        enter2 = enterbox(msg="Enter the child's last name.", title=' ', default='', strip=True, image=None, root=None)  # ask user to enter child's first name
        while enter2 == "" or enter2.isalpha() == False:
            if enter2 is None:
                main()
            else:
                enter2 = enterbox(msg="Invalid entry. Please enter the child's last name using letters only.", title=' ', default='', strip=True, image=None,root=None)

                child_name = (enter1 + " " + enter2).title()
                file = open("Children.txt", 'a')
                file.write(child_name + "\n")
                file.close()

    if button == children_menu[1]:
        file = open("Children.txt", 'r')
        lineList = file.readlines()
        lineList.sort()  
        print("List of children's names in alphabetical order:")
        for line in lineList:
            print(line, end="")
        file.close()
        main()

def main():
    title1 = "Main menu."
    main_menu = ["1: Children", "2: Groups", "3: Educators", "4: Tags", "5: Cancel"]
    button = buttonbox("Choose an option", title1, choices=main_menu)

    if button == main_menu[0]:
        children_menu()


    elif button == main_menu[1]:
        group_menu()

    elif button == main_menu[2]:
        button = "3"
        title4 = "Educators."
        educator_menu = ["1: Register an educator.", "2: List of registered educators."]
        button = buttonbox("Choose an option", title4, choices=educator_menu)

    elif button == main_menu[3]:
        button = "4"
        title4 = "Tags."
        tags_menu = ["1: Create tags", "2: List of tags."]
        button = buttonbox("Choose an option", title4, choices=tags_menu)

    else:
        button = "You cancelled."

main()
```

#### Questions

1. Why does the code continue to the while-loop even though the user's choice  returns a *NoneType* ?
2. Doesn't it meet the condition of the if-statement?
3. Shouldn't the script return to the `main()` function that is being called?

Comment: It doesn't.  `None` is not the same as an empty string.  Try: `print('Is enter1 None: {}'.format(enter1 is None))` in your while loop.

Comment: Also, your indenting is off.  Your posted code would likely produce a syntax error.

Comment: yes i know. it's not checking to see if it's an empty string. the if condition is checking to see if the user chose the 'cancel' option on the enterbox which returns 'None'. So if the user hits 'cancel' and the condition checks for that, why is the condition not true?

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell you exactly what is wrong without seeing the rest of the code (what does `main()` do?).  If you comment out the `main()` call, does it work?

Comment: If you remove the `default=''` parameter, does it still do that?

Comment: your code works fine to me.  If I choose 'children', 'register a child' and 'cancel', it goes back to the main menu

Comment: Gerrat: yes it does unfortunately

Comment: robert_x44 what happens when you hit Cancel on the enter box when asked to enter the child's first name?

Comment: Also, you may like 120 char lines, but if you want someone else to look at your code, it's helpful to wrap your lines :)

Comment: robert_x44: Thank you, I'll remember that in the future.

Comment: Are you sure you've saved before running?  And when you're debugging, if you're unsure why a condition is or isn't tripping, add `print(enter1)` before the condition.

Comment: Your code works fine for me too.  Maybe you're not running what you think you are.

Comment: I do all of those things and have saved the code. It's a mystery to me. I know it should work and the proof is that it works for you both.

Comment: What does it print with a `print(enter1)` statement added just before the `if enter1 is None:` statement.

Comment: absolutely nothing

Comment: I copied and pasted the code onto a new file and ran it and for some reason it now works, even though it's exactly the same code.

Comment: Please add clarifying questions and your answering comments to your question to refine it. Currently it is not clear and asking 3 questions. Please find help in [ask].